# Cannot parse JSON with huge value

Tags: php, json

In my JSON I have 4 root values. 3 of them are parsed just good. The 4th dict is not even in the result. In this dict there is a UTF-8 string with key "base64" which length is 50915 symbols.

This happens only on the server (PHP 5.3.*), on my local (PHP 5.4.4) all works fine. What the hell is going on? Is there a limit on one object size?

## Code

```php
$json   = new Services_JSON(SERVICES_JSON_LOOSE_TYPE);
$result = $json->decode($var);
```

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: @j0k Added the code, but there's nothing interesting.

Comment: Have you tried with [`json_decode`](http://php.net/function.json-decode.php) instead? I see that you can force the *depth*.

Comment: @j0k Thanks, it worked! Don't know why I'd been using this code in this case, `json_decode` is better for sure. Leave an answer so I could mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/function.json-decode.php) instead.

As far as I know, the PEAR library to handle JSON was build because there were no proper way to handle JSON before PHP 5.1. I think you can leave this library aside and use `json_*` function instead.